# Difficulty running a .NET MVC Application from within a Classic ASP site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp-classic, iis-8

I am trying to run a .NET MVC 5 Application using C# from within a Classic ASP site on IIS 8. The Classic ASP site is running with an App Pool set for .NET v2.0. I created a new App Pool for the .NET Application to run under using .NET v4.0. Both are running in Integrated Pipeline mode.

When I attempt to browse to the .NET Application I keep getting:

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.`
```

So, at this point I'm unsure if I need to alter my IIS configuration or how I am building the .NET app. I am new to MVC and this is my first attempt at trying to integrate a .NET Application into Classic ASP. Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The key to getting this running for me was to install ASP.NET 4.5 from within Server Manager > Add Roles and Features > IIS Web Server > Application Development. I also added in IIS Manager ISAPI Filters for the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of .NET v4.0 located at `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll` and `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll.`

Hope this helps some unlucky person wrangling with Classic ASP and .NET!